# Changing values type of my df

Tags: pandas

I have a df:

```
                   0
        venta     0,00
        Infra     0,00
        Neutr     14,00
        Sobre     2,00 
        Fuerte    11,00
```

The df is made from an array and  the `type(df.values)` is a `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` .

I think the values class explains why I cannot turn the df values into `floats`.

How can I change the type of the values in order to operate with the values column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) `,` to `.` first and then cast by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html).

```
#if numeric column change '0' to 0 only
df['0'] = df['0'].replace(',','.', regex=True).astype(float)
#alternative
#df['0'] = df['0'].str.replace(',','.').astype(float)
print (df)
           0
venta    0.0
Infra    0.0
Neutr   14.0
Sobre    2.0
Fuerte  11.0
```

But if some non numeric data need [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` for replace them to `NaN`s:

```
df['0'] = pd.to_numeric(df['0'].replace(',','.', regex=True), errors='coerce')
print (df)

           0
venta    0.0
Infra    0.0
Neutr   14.0
Sobre    2.0
Fuerte  11.0
```

If use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) function, is possible use `decimal` parameter for change default value `decimal='.'`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, decimal=',')
```

Comment: Arises `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '11,00'`

Comment: Thank you jezrael , had a hard struggle with this one!