# Getting NaN's in mutiple columns after pivoting

Tags: python, pandas

I need to pivot a dataframe (dfM) which looks something like

```
Task Question Answer analystID
x    a        1      u
y    b        2      i
z    c        3      o
```

I want to pivot it so that the analyst IDs are the headers and the Answers are what is filled under the headers, with the Task and Question as index.
Initially I tried

```
dfM['Answer'] = pd.to_numeric(dfM['Answer'], errors='coerce')

dfP = pd.pivot_table(dfM, index = ['Task', 'Question'], columns = 'analystID', 
                     values = ['Answer'])
```

because I was getting a No Numeric Types to aggregate error, but now all the Answers that are supposed to be under the headers are NaNs. 
Is there a good way to fix this problem?

Comment: I tried dfM['Answer'] = pd.to_numeric(dfM['Answer'].str.strip(), errors='coerce'), and it seems to still return NaNs

Comment: Hmmm, if there is only a few numeric, it can works right. You can check all parsed numeric by `print (dfM.loc[pd.to_numeric(dfM['Answer'], errors='coerce').notnull(), 'Answer']))`

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple problems.

**1.**

Trailing whitespaces with numbers.

Solution is [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
dfM['Answer'] = pd.to_numeric(dfM['Answer'].str.strip(), errors='coerce')
```

**2.**

Some `;` instead `.` in floats:

Solution is [replace with points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45719787/2901002).

**3.**

If doest work nothing, try check values manually and check numeric:

```
print (dfM['Answer'].tolist())
```

Comment: The first two give me the same thing as before, all NaNs in a column

Comment: well i did the 3rd thing, and the it returned all Nans

Comment: I want the rows under the column "Answer" to be numeric, but for some reason now its all NaNs

Comment: are data confidental?

Comment: OK. do you check `print (dfM['Answer'].tolist())` of original data, especailly numeric values without any strings?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can see what is wrong with your 'Answer' column,
is to find the letters in the strings that are not numerics

```
dfm= pd.DataFrame({'Answer': ['1', '2 ', '3o', '1,000']})

def find_non_num(x):
    uniq= set(str(x))
    nums= set(['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'])
    return uniq - nums

dfm.Answer.apply(find_non_num) #optional .unique()
#the output will be:
#0     {}
#1    { }
#2    {o}
#3    {,}
```

In this way you can see what happened that made your NaNs appear,
Moreover, you can use the `.unique()` method to find what kinds of errors are there,
and boolean indexing to see which rows have what problem and how does it behave

```
dfm.Answer[dfm.Answer.str.find('o') > -1]  #returns Series of [3o] with index 2
```